# Could Not Retrive any Response Data from Given URL

Tags: android, json

I can retrieve JSON data from same code but failed to retrieve data from  this url, why this is not returning any response code or not coming with any data response. Please help me to resolve this, or suggest me how to retrieve non JSON data from web url.

```
   URL uniprotFasta = new URL(ur);
  url = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P69905.fasta";

 URL uniprotFasta = new URL(ur);
 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) uniprotFasta.openConnection();
    conn.connect();
    int response = conn.getResponseCode();
    Log.e("Response Code * *", String.valueOf(response));
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    // Convert the InputStream into a string
    String contentAsString = readIt(is, 500);
    Log.e("HTTPURLCON * *",contentAsString);
```

I have also tried this one but received nothing in response.

```
String data = "";
URLConnection conn = uniprotFasta.openConnection();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
     data += line;
}
Log.e("DATA * *",data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have tried this for you.

1. Write your code in Asyntask.

   ```
   public class TestUrl extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       String url = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P69905.fasta";
       HttpURLConnection conn = null;
       InputStream is = null;
       try {
           URL uniprotFasta = new URL(url);
           conn = (HttpURLConnection) uniprotFasta.openConnection();
           conn.connect();
           int response = conn.getResponseCode();
           Log.e("Response Code * *", String.valueOf(response));
           is = conn.getInputStream();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       // Convert the InputStream into a string
       String contentAsString = convertStreamToString(is);
       Log.e("HTTPURLCON * *", contentAsString);

       return null;
   }
   ```
2. Function that will convert input stream to String

   ```
   private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   String line = null;
   try {
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           sb.append(line).append('\n');
       }
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
       try {
           is.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   return sb.toString();
   ```

   }
3. Give permission in Manifest file

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   ```
4. Execute Asynctask that will run the code in background thread.

   ```
   new TestUrl().execute();
   ```
5. Response you will get is

   ```
   E/Response Code * *: 200
   E/HTTPURLCON * *: >sp|P69905|HBA_HUMAN Hemoglobin subunit alpha OS=Homo    sapiens GN=HBA1 PE=1 SV=2
             MVLSPADKTNVKAAWGKVGAHAGEYGAEALERMFLSFPTTKTYFPHFDLSHGSAQVKGHG
             KKVADALTNAVAHVDDMPNALSALSDLHAHKLRVDPVNFKLLSHCLLVTLAAHLPAEFTP
             AVHASLDKFLASVSTVLTSKYR
   ```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Code reaches to try block but could not run openConnection() and thats why it print nothing once again, what you think there is something else wrong here.

Comment: Have you checked your internet connection on device ?

Comment: write down your log of exception.

Comment: I was connected to wifi, i changed to my data and sucess , THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: Hi, can we parse response from this site, http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/?term=opsin

Answer (score 0):

```
//you Should Declare Header type , Content 

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String urlService="http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P69905.fasta";
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlService);

    try {

        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception" +e);
    }
}
```